# Store a table in an array

Tags: r

I have a table which is generated in a loop and which will always have 5 columns but can have anything between 50 to 100 rows. I would like to save each's loop table in an array. However, when I declare

```
mat<-array(NA,dim=c(20,100,5))
mat[t,,]<-table
```

where t is the loop running variable I get an error `Error in mat[,,] number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.
 Could somebody tell me how I could just save the table in an array ?

Comment: Show your loop (and then we can explain to you why you don't need it). At least show an example of `dput(table)`. Note that a `table` is a specific data structure in R.

Comment: As Roland said we need an example. The way I would go about this is by generating a list as an output. E.g. 

x <- rep(1:10,1)
y <- rep(1:10,2)
z <- rep(1:10,3)

list(x,y,z)